# Pig Dump Not Showing All Digits

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have loaded data into Hadoop using Pig, but when I dump the csv table, it looks like my data was divided by one million. Original CSV:

```
state   population
California  39144818
Texas   27469114
Florida 20271272
```

Pig code to load:

```
statePopFile =LOAD 'hdfs:/home/ubuntu/final/gunData/statePops.csv' using             PigStorage(',');
stateRec = FOREACH statePopFile GENERATE $0 AS state ,$1 as population;
dump stateRec;
```

The output from the console looks like this

```
(California,"39)
(Texas,"27)
(Florida,"20)
```

Comment: Is your input `.csv` file in tab formatted ?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was loading the data in and separating on ','. That was cutting of the number. This was resolved by separating on \t